# Recursive Function Explanation

Tags: php, function, recursion

I have a question about a recursive function.  I have a good idea about what it's doing but I need it explained to me in a bit more detail.  I understand that it's passing $val, the $pattern to check for and boolean of $suspect.  **But why call the function recursively back to itself?**  I suppose what I think it's trying to do is check if $val is an array, if it is an array then loop through it and take the $item and pass that item (Ex: [$_POST['name']..) and see if it's an array. Obviously, it would be a string and at that point the first if statement would fail because the $item is a string and then it would jump down to the the preg_match function checking to see if that string contains the pattern we set to check for in $pattern.

Am I on the right track?  My question is why pass the function recursively back to itself?

### CODE:

```
// Assume nothing is suspect
$suspect = false;

// Create a pattern to locate suspect phrases
$pattern = '/Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';

// Function to check for suspect phrases

function isSuspect($val, $pattern, &$suspect) {
if(is_array($val)) {
    foreach($val as $item) {
        isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
    }
} else {
    // If one of the suspect phrases is found, set Boolean to true
    if (preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
        $suspect = true;
        }
    }
}

   // check the $_POST array and any subarrays for suspect content
   isSuspect($_POST, $pattern, $suspect);
```

Comment: The comment in the code already explains it: "check the $_POST array and any subarrays"

Comment: Right.  But why pass the function back to itself in the first if statement?  And is my thinking on the right track as to WHY they are doing that?

Comment: In order to iterate the arrays and any subarrays it contains, and any subarrays they contain.

Comment: because, if you have a multidimensional array you, and if you need check all the array content, you need re enter to each internal array as a new one array and repeat the validations.

Comment: Ok, so it's like iterating and finding a $_POST array which IS an array and then grabbing the $val as $item like $_POST['name'] which ['name'] is then getting set to $item and now that will be checked for an array but it's a string, the first IF statement would fail and then get checked below?  

Additionally, let's say the code iterated through one string and checked it.  When would it fire back up the first IF statement to check the rest of the form?

Comment: Well, I guess it would only need to find one match for the whole thing to fail so it wouldn't need to check the rest of the form.  :)

Comment: Thanks guys!  Still new to PHP and learning.  Thanks for the patience!

Comment: $_POST['name'] *might* be a string, but it could equally be an array such as $_POST['name']['first'], $_POST['name']['last']. $_POST [can contain arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays). The function has to be recursive to iterate those arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing a value like this into the isSubject function:

```
$val = array(arrray(array(1,2,3),4),5);
```

Through recursion you make shure that:

1. every time you hit an array, dig deeper
2. every time you hit a string, compare it to the pattern
3. keep track if we found the subject with a global state variable called $suspect

so to say in the given example, the

1. level of recursion: examine array(arrray(array(1,2,3),4),5);
2. level of recursion: examine arrray(array(1,2,3),4) and 5
3. level of recursion: examine array(1,2,3) and 4
4. level of recursion: examine 1 and 2 and 3